# Get Div's new left position percentage on drag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on resizing a div on drag an updating it's left position accordingly.

The div starts in the center of the page using the following CSS style

```
left: `calc (50% + ${offsetX})`
```

where the values offsetX is initially 0. When a user clicks and drags on one of the resize handles the offsetX value will be updated according so that the div stays in the same posistion, but the width increases.

```
width: initialWidth + offsetX * 2
```

However, this only works when the div is still in the middle of the page. Once I drag the div somewhere else and try to resize it, it sort of jumps position because it's calculation is still based of the left position being at 50%. Is there any way I can get the new percentage left position of the div on drag so that I can do something like below

```
left: leftPercent === 0 ? `calc (50% + ${offsetX})` : `calc (${leftPercent}% + ${offsetX})`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it using the element's left position and `screen.width` like this:

```
function getPercent(elementLeft) {
  return elementLeft / screen.width * 100;
}
```